# NiFi InvokeHTTP Processor: On NiFi 1.10.0 OK, on Nifi 1.11.4 error okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException

Tags: apache-nifi

I've go a simple **InvokeHTTP** Prozessor

```
Method: POST
Remote URL: https://(ServerName)/auth/realms/Sherlock/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}
```

On my **NiFi 1.10.0** system all works fine

But on a **NiFi 1.11.4** system I get:

```
2020-07-28 13:11:44,256 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP InvokeHTTP[id=c9df8eec-b142-3243-52f1-b9351feb6705] Routing to Failure due to exception: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException: okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException
okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException: null
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:219)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.newStream(Http2Connection.java:205)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.writeRequestHeaders(Http2Codec.java:106)
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Frank

Comment: Have you tried connecting using [HTTP/2 via `curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) to this server to verify that it supports HTTP/2?

Comment: @Andy: since the processor works with this server under NiFi 1.10 and the problem comes up with the update to 1.11, I do not think that's a problem of the server ;)

Comment: Well, as the code in `InvokeHTTP` changed between NiFi 1.10 and 1.11.4, the connection attempt could be done in a different manner now. I am not saying it is the server's "fault", I am asking if you verified that HTTP/2 connections through a different mechanism work on that server.